# Focus iPhone torch to a beam

Tags: optics

I would like to focus an iPhone 5s' torch light into a beam with an angle of around 5 degrees or smaller (hopefully). Is this easily doable with a single lens?

I'm hoping to buy a lens and attach it in front of the iPhone (by 3D-printing a custom case). I just don't know which lens I should get.

This is for an artistic project. It doesn't have to be very precise. Since I will be using around 75 iPhones, I'm hoping the lens to be fairly cheap and easy to get in bulk.

Any input is appreciated. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generating a reasonably collimated beam from an iPhone is only possible if:

1. You use an enormous lens (several inches in diameter), in which case your beam will be correspondingly enormous.
2. You are willing to throw away a lot of the light by using a pinhole positioned on the lamp surface in addition to the lens.

The reason these compromises are necessary is that the iPhone lamp is about 4 mm across and thus does not act suitably like a point source unless the lens diameter is much larger. Since a lens has only a single focal point, it will only nicely collimate a diverging beam if the beam originates from a single location. So for a small lens with a short focal length, you’ll need to block most of the iPhone lamp with a pinhole (a “spatial filter”).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the insights. If I did block most of the light and left a hole 1mm in diameter, would that be suitable? If so, what kind of lens could I be using? (as you perhaps guessed, I am not too concerned by the loss in light intensity)

Comment: @djip.co this is going to depend on what exactly you want it to look like. A 1 mm source will be easier to collimate, but still not good enough if you want a small diameter beam with little divergence. The kind of lens (size, focal length, material, etc.) is all going to depend on practical considerations.

Comment: I don't really have any preconceived idea of how it should look. I just want a narrower beam than what the iPhone normally provides, hopefully something that looks good when shining on smoke. I may just try a small diode laser plastic lens and see how it performs. I've seen some of them that are 7mm in diameter with a 8mm focus distance. What do you think?

Comment: @djip.co oh, I think that would look cool. Totally worth a try! But you won’t have a nicely collimated beam. It’s still going to diverge quite a bit. Maybe that’s okay?

Comment: @djip.co on the other hand, if you wanted to use lasers, you could get them waaay cheaper than iPhones, and then you could do whatever you want with their nice, collimated beams.

Comment: The project I'm working on addresses issues of planned obsolescence and how we deal with "old", unwanted technology. That's why I chose the iPhone as my platform of choice. The project is not about light, it's about reinventing a second life for devices that are deemed garbage... For context, I did a similar project with old plotters: https://djip.co/art/yoti

Comment: I did buy the lenses. They are cheap enough for me to just try them out. We'll see... Anyway, thanks a lot for helping out a clueless optics newbie!